# C# How to download audio file from googlevideos.com/videoplayback url

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, youtube, extract

I have a url (example) of audio format from a youtube video

```
https://rr6---sn-n8v7znsr.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1691861737&ei=iW7XZM3hHciwv_IP3oe_oAk&ip=kekw&id=o-AH6t-rpPJjbEN9qDVOJlCEU2FTLNrvRtMslTqQ0T4as4&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=QC&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-n8v7znsr%2Csn-c0q7lnse&ms=au%2Conr&mv=m&mvi=6&pl=21&gcr=ru&initcwndbps=1281250&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=1641566&dur=108.561&lmt=1689370605701687&mt=1691839772&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=24007246&c=ANDROID_TESTSUITE&txp=5432434&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cgcr%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIgV1LPFsKrQ558nwhqkatBGRWchRXYBWo1fSrc0fSujtkCIQDfpHxCk8hwwyTezP6e6yIGXR7yGNxLfv9qEkP99C_eiw%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIgFvFgT1ALo6OrKY_QRvD6-XilXezUdxdObEtQ3Xo9DaQCIQCD-LWIv8v0y04x0ZExDjfZ_kFZbbxBYHaDejTILMmHug%3D%3D
```

that I can open in browser and click "download" button to download webm file, but how do I do this in C# code?

Let's say I have a method like this:

```
public async Task Download(string url) { }
```

In short. I'm trying to download audio from youtube video by clicking a button on UWP form. Tried using [YoutubeExplode](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode) to download audio by video id, but as I'm writing on UWP I'm unable to use File class that used in this library bc access is always denied. VideoLibrary + MediaToolKit also not a good idea as it downloads video and then convert it to audio format (takes much time). All I can get now are video&audio formats and their urls (like above) and info about videos by Youtube API requests.

Comment: Have you declared the capability [broadFileSystemAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#example) in Package.appxmanifest and have the [file permissions turned on](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/-windows-file-system-access-and-privacy-a7d90b20-b252-0e7b-6a29-a3a688e5c7be#:~:text=How%20the%20file%20system%20access%20settings%20work.%20To,to%20access%20your%20file%20system%20is%20turned%20On.) in App Settings?

Comment: @Junjie Zhu - MSFT Yes, I did. It's said on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) `This capability works for APIs in the Windows.Storage namespace. ` for broadFileSystemAccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpClient + Windows.Storage works fine with that, but takes too long to download bc

> For most streams, YouTube limits transfer speed to match the video
> playback rate. This helps them avoid unnecessary bandwidth, but for us
> it's a hindrance because we want to download the stream as fast as
> possible. To solve this, we divide the logical stream up into multiple
> segments and download them all separately.

that is another topic...

Working code:

```
public async Task Download(string url)
{
    StorageFile destination = await (await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("dl-path"))
      .CreateFileAsync("name", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

    byte[] buffer = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
    using (Stream stream = await destination.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        // renaming to control download status
        await destination.RenameAsync("name" + ".mp3");
    }
}
```